# Can Jira be configured to strip absolute URLs pointing to tickets inside the same instance?

Tags: configuration, jira

So we're using Jira in the company and over the years the URL of the Jira instance has changed. So for example the base URL changed from http://domain1.tld/ to http://domain2.tld/

Users, however, keep pasting the URLs to link to issues inside the instance. So prior to the base URL change people would paste `http://domain1.tld/browse/ABC-123` and now that link is effectively broken. Even while the old domain name was kept online, the result would be that you would end up on the old URL and not be logged into it.

Is there a way to strip all absolute URLs right during/after the comment or ticket is created to not have that issue in the first place?

Comment: Although this doesn't solve the historical problem, the best way going forward is to train users to enter the correct type of "links" in the first place. In most places, JIRA will automatically convert plain text such as "ABC-123" into a link to the indicated issue, so there is no need to use any sort of URL (absolute or relative). Or perhaps that is what you actually meant by "relative URL"? In any case, placing a text widget on the system dashboard can be useful for showing "Did you know that you can ... ?" PSA-type messages to try to retrain the masses.

Comment: @ScottDudley: thanks, I even *know* this would be the best option. But it's harder to change people than to change software. Yes, I meant the shorthand (`ABC-123`) as "relative", although I didn't use the term anywhere :) ... I had brought up that topic early on with the guy who *was* nominally responsible for our Jira instance. He ignored it and closed the ticket as rejected. As I wrote: it's damn hard to change people and it might be easier to change the software as a start (it could also be a plugin rejecting absolute URLs to our Jira instance).

Comment: @ScottDudley: I should add that I'd prefer relative links also in case of links to comments or attachments, though.

Answer (score 1):

You would be looking at something like a [`Jira Issue Listener`](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Listeners) through either a custom JIRA plugin (Java) or you could look into the [`Script Runner`](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.groovy.groovyrunner) plugin and create a `Script Listener`. (Groovy)

What you can do is if JIRA is fronted by Webserver (Ex. Apache) is point the DNS entry for `domain1.tld` to the new JIRA instance and setup a Virtual Host to redirect the user from `domain1.tld` the correct location on `domain2.tld`.

The Apache Rewrite rule would be like:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain2.tld/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: thanks, I know about redirects and rewrites. Alas, it appears our admins don't. At least numerous suggestions to use that as a route to mitigate the issue fell on deaf ears. The script runner is likely closer to what is needed. Like I responded to Scott Dudley above: sometimes it's easier to fix software than to fix people ;)